# Android Phonegap swipe type

Tags: android, cordova

I am developing an application in Android Phonegap. I need to apply swype in my application. How to apply? Anybody kindly guide me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use jGestures jQuery library (http://jgestures.codeplex.com/), or jQuery mobile or other libraries for gesture events.

Then, if you use jGestures, you catch a swipe like so jQuery('#swipe').bind('swipedown',eventHandler);

I'm using this library and it processes gestures pretty fast.

You can download decoupled jQuery Mobile library only for touch events, too.