# Swiping in Cordova with Jquery and jgestures

Tags: jquery, swipe-gesture

There are lots of topics in Stackoverflow when it comes to swiping using jQuery/jQuery mobile. However, none of them seem to work in the manner I want. The following is the structure of my index page of my phonegap app. As [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10978279/android-phonegap-swipe-type) topic recommended, I tried jgestures plugin.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>App</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="lib/cordova-2.2.0.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="lib/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="lib/jgestures.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="home">
    <div id="headersec">
        <!-- some elements like images here-->
    </div>
    <div id="screen1">
        <!-- three 80x80 images go here -->
    </div>
    <div id="screen2">
        <!-- three other 80x80 images go here-->
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

All I want to do in my deviceready event is this

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready",onDeviceReady,false);

function onDeviceReady() {
    $('#screen1').bind('swipeleft',showNext); //show next hides screen1, shows screen2 
    $('#screen2').bind('swiperight',showPrev);//show prev hides screen2, shows screen1
}
```

But this does not work with any of the sample code I've tried.. Can anyone tell what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Looks like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8982728/deviceready-not-working-in-phonegap-application-how-to) question had a similar issue.  The solution was do something like this:

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", function(){
    $('#screen1').bind('swipeleft',showNext); //show next hides screen1, shows screen2 
    $('#screen2').bind('swiperight',showPrev);//show prev hides screen2, shows screen1
},false);
```

Or perhaps you simply need to define the function `onDeviceReady` BEFORE you call the event listener.

Comment: There is no difference between this code and the code in the question. Defining function inline or separately does not make any difference. What was the solution, really?